# Jquery keyup does not detect the result in the input of Alt + code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am validating an input for a password, where I require that the user must enter at least one special character, for example: (@#$%&.), in my code with jquery I am detecting the keyup event to evaluate what the user writes, while I write in the input all the characters are written correctly, until I try to do the @ with the key combination Alt + 64, the event detects when the Alt is pressed but in the result of the jquery code where I look for the value of the input it is not there the @ even though it is in the input.

This is my jquery code to evaluate the keyup event:

```
function validate_pass(element) {
  let password = $(element).val();
  if (!(/^(.{8,20}$)/.test(password))) {
    return 'It must be between 8 and 20 characters.';
  }
  else if (!(/^(?=.*[A-Z])/.test(password))) {
    return 'It must contain at least one capital letter.';
  }
  else if (!(/^(?=.*[a-z])/.test(password))) {
    return 'It must contain at least one lowercase letter.';
  }
  else if (!(/^(?=.*[0-9])/.test(password))) {
    return 'It must contain at least one digit (0-9).';
  }
  else if (!(/^(?=.*[@#$%&])/.test(password))) {
    return "Must contain special characters (@#$%&).";
  }
  return true;
}
$('#user-pass').on('keyup',(e)=>{
  if(e.which == 20 || e.which == 16){ //prevent bloq mayus and shift
    return false;
  } 
  console.log($('#user-pass').val()); 
  let resp = validate_pass('#user-pass');
  if(resp == true){
    $('label[for="user-pass"]').text('Password').css('color','#9e9e9e');
    $('#user-pass').removeClass('invalid');
    $('#user-pass').addClass('valid');
  }else{
    $('label[for="user-pass"]').text(resp).css('color','red');
    $('#user-pass').addClass('invalid');
  }
});
```

Let's imagine that I write the following password in the input so that I test the code: Jhon000@
In the console I get the following results:

```
J
Jh
Jho
John
Jhon0
Jhon00
Jhon000
```

but when I execute the combination of Alt + 64 to write the @ the console shows me this again in the log:

Jhon000

and I have to press some other key so that the keyup event shows me Jhon000@ in the console, for example I use the same Alt key.

Comment: Put `console.log("Prevented input");` after `if(e.which == 20 || e.which == 16){`. Proper debugging means putting console logs in every possible route so you can see what's going on instead of just wondering why "it doesn't work"

Comment: @icecub don't use Event.which, we're not robots, we're developers. Use rather `Event.key` or `Event.code`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan "which" = "which key was up'd" ?

Comment: Don't use `keyup` - use `input`.   keyup is correctly reporting the keys as the "up" - ie 6, 4, alt - but these don't change the input at that time, only after (as you've found).   Equally, if you *hold down* a key you only get 1 keyup.

Comment: right-click, paste also doesn't use `keyup`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I'm just replying to OP's own code. I know not use `event.which`, as evident in my answer to this question.

Comment: @icecub I mistakenly "@"tted *you* instead of *Francisco*.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Ah alright, it happens. No worries!

Answer (score 0):

I found a strange solution, but it works. I just had to put a setTimeout inside the code that detects the event, like this:

```
  $('#user-pass').on('keyup',(e)=>{
    if(e.which == 20 || e.which == 16){
      return false;
    }
    setTimeout(()=>{
      let resp = validate_pass('#user-pass');
      if(resp == true){
        $('label[for="user-pass"]').text('Contraseña').css('color','#9e9e9e');
        $('#user-pass').removeClass('invalid');
        $('#user-pass').addClass('valid');
      }else{
        $('label[for="user-pass"]').text(resp).css('color','red');
        $('#user-pass').addClass('invalid');
      }
    },50);
  });
```

and this just fixed the problem.

I found this solution in the following link: https://github.com/jquery/api.jquery.com/issues/386

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `keyup` event is triggered every time a key is being released.

Here's an example that shows the actual behavior:

```js
$('#my').on('keyup', function(e){
  console.log(e.key + ' has been released!');
});

function getValue(){
  console.log("The field's current value is: "+ $('#my').val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="my"><br/><br/>
<button onclick="getValue()">Get Value!</button>
```

When you use Alt+Num codes, the `keyup` event is being triggered every time you release a number. The keyboard however does not input anything into the field as it waits for you to release the Alt key.

Once you release the Alt key, it actually does trigger the `keyup` event. However, it takes a fraction of a second for your computer to get the correct special character, by which time the `keyup` event is already finished. Hence setting a timeout "fixes" the issue, as it simply gives your pc the time it needs to input the special character.